# How to perform the following query?

Tags: soql, query

I am trying to retrieve records using ContentDocument and ContentDocumentLink but the following query isn't working as expected.

```
SELECT id, ContentDocumentId, ContentDocument.CreatedDate, ContentDocument.Title, ContentDocument.FileType, ContentDocument.FileExtension, sharetype, LinkedEntityId  
FROM ContentDocumentLink 
WHERE ContentDocumentId IN 
    (SELECT ContentDocumentId 
         FROM ContentVersion 
         WHERE FileExtension = ' ' OR FileType = ' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

*Because of some restrictions of salesforce like that*
**"Implementation restriction: ContentDocumentLink requires a filter by a single Id on ContentDocumentId or LinkedEntityId using the equals operator or multiple Id's using the IN operator."**

Try this approach

```
map<Id,ContentVersion> mapOfContentVersion = new map<Id,ContentVersion>(
          [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion 
              WHERE FileExtension = 'pdf' OR FileType = 'png']);
Set<Id> newSet = mapOfContentVersion.keySet();
List<ContentDocumentLink> DocumentLinkLIst = [SELECT id,ContentDocumentId,
                                        ContentDocument.CreatedDate,
                                        ContentDocument.Title, 
                                        ContentDocument.FileType,                                        ContentDocument.FileExtension,
                                        sharetype, LinkedEntityId 
                                           FROM ContentDocumentLink 
                                           WHERE ContentDocumentId IN :newSet];
```